# At what age is the Force detectable in children?

Tags: star-wars, the-force

Training of [Jedi younglings](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jedi_youngling) ranged between the ages of 4 and 8 but at what age was a Jedi able to feel a Force sensitive child? Is it from birth or at around 4 years?

Comment: Sigh. [Midi-chlorians](http://www.starwars.com/news/so-what-the-heck-are-midi-chlorians)

Comment: @Valorum - That link is pretty interesting. It does make me wonder, though. We’ve seen how people with high midi-chlorian counts and no training interact (mainly subconsciously, through luck bonuses to things like combat and flying), how people with high midi-chlorian counts and training interact (superhuman abilities and psychic powers) and how people with low midi-chlorian counts and no training interact (boring baseline sentients). I wonder what would happen if someone with low midi-chlorian counts trained in the ways of the Force. Could they develop some Force abilities?

Comment: Obviously the Jedi or Sith aren’t going to take Jane or Joe Sarlacc with their midichlorian count of six, but if they did, could Joe or Jane tap into the Force at all? Obviously they’re never going to shoot blue lightning from their fingers, but could they achieve some (low) level of Force competence? A 100 pound person may find it difficult to wrestle with a 300 person, but they can still get a lot better with training.

Comment: The linked duplicate indicates that midi-chlorian blood testing (at least within the core worlds) was **normally done at birth**.

Comment: @adamant - The principle is that it's not *perceptible* in real terms, but all living beings are connected to the Force. A strong non-Jedi might be slightly more intuitive or seem lucky, for example.

Comment: I’m going with [Shog9](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9748/51379) on this one. Just because two questions can be answered with the same animated gif (or quote block), does not mean they are duplicates. The indication that testing is at birth is in a quote block in the answer, and not every good answer to that question would mention testing at birth.

Comment: To wit: `But this doesn’t hold if a question has managed to attract a lot of different answers - so you end up in situations like this where various answers might be applied to completely different questions even though most of the answers are inapplicable. Frankly, this is a wee bit silly, and smells more of folks being bored with the topic than anything else.` **What’s more, there’s also the issue of the answer to that question coming from a Legends source, whereas questions are generally presumed canon unless noted.**

Comment: Related to [What is the right age for starting a training for Jedi?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/45506/what-is-the-right-age-for-starting-a-training-for-jedi) from other site.

Comment: To clarify that last point: the other question was asking about a Legends topic, so an answer that quoted a Legends text about Jedi testing was fine. But this question is probably asking about canon, so the Legends quote block does not really answer it.

Comment: @adamant - I disagree. If this gets reopened, I'm sure I can find some other sources that say much the same thing, but why bother when it already has a high quality answer elsewhere.

Comment: @Valorum - Of course; you’re the one that closed it. ;) But if it gets reopened and you do find a better dupe target, of course that’s good.

Comment: It doesn’t quite have a high-quality answer in that other question: it’s briefly addressed by a quote snippet in an substantially different continuity. The answer itself is high quality, sure, but doesn’t really answer this question.

Comment: @adamant - It directly addresses the question.  When are they detectable? At birth. That's all that's needed for it to be a dupe.

Comment: @Valorum The answer to the linked question uses a Legends source in its claim that Force sensitivity is detectable at birth. However, there is no indication in this question that Legends sources are acceptable for it -- so I do not think the linked answer addresses this question and I am re-opening this one.

Comment: @Null - There's no indication from the OP that he's only after canon sources. That's your assumption, not his.

Comment: @Valorum Didn't Leia feel the force in Ben when she was pregnant with him in Bloodlines?

Comment: @CBredlow - You're thinking of Life Debt. Leia uses her Force ability to sense the child, not the other way around.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Canon

According to the Phantom Menace official novelisation, all children within the Republic are blood-tested at a very early age, typically just after birth.

> But **all Jedi were identified within the first six months of birth and
> given over to their training.** It was true for him, for Obi-Wan, for
> everyone he knew or had heard about. There were no exceptions.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars Episode I: The Phantom Menace](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_I:_The_Phantom_Menace_(novel))</sup></sub>

and

> ***Like most Jedi, Obi-Wan is identified within six months of his birth
> and begins his training immediately** so that he can learn to control
> emotions of fear and anger at an early age*
>
> <sub><sup>[Ultimate Star Wars](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ultimate_Star_Wars)</sup></sub>

### Legends

The ["The Jedi Path: A Manual for Students of the Force"](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Jedi_Path:_A_Manual_for_Students_of_the_Force_(real-life_book)) factbook contains an extensive section on Jedi recruitment. Apparently blood-testing is mandatory and the Jedi have the legal authority to take a child into their custody if they're found to have significant Midi-chlorian counts. Apparently some children do slip through the net and are *manually tested* in the same way that Anakin was.

> Locating Force-strong newborns is a straightforward process, at least
> within the Republic’s borders. **Mandatory blood tests performed at
> birth record the concentration of midi-chlorians in an infants cells,
> and positive results are forwarded to the Jedi Temple for follow-up.**
>
> Because midi-chlorian analysis is not always definitive — particularly
> among older children or beings with unusual physiologies — special
> tools or puzzles may be employed instead. These include the testing
> screen, a tool that records a subject’s ability to read minds or view
> images remotely, and the mental maze, a test that demonstrates whether
> a subject can use rudimen¬tary telekinesis.

Comment: This answer uses a canon source, and is more concise and relevant to this question than the linked answer. Much better. +1

Comment: @Null - Which is fine, except that the OP didn't ask for a canon source. They may have been perfectly happy with a Legends answer.

Comment: The OP didn't say Legends was acceptable, either. According to the [highest-voted answer to the relevant meta question](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/8055/31936) the best practice is to answer these kinds of questions with both canon and Legends, as you've done here. The same meta answer also says that "answers based *solely* on Legends material should generally be avoided". As a corollary to that guideline, I think we should generally avoid closing questions as duplicates just because there's a Legends-only answer that might be acceptable to the OP.

Comment: @Valorum Thanks, I didn't state I wanted either (probably should have) because i was looking for both.